# "first" helper method

Tags: ruby, methods, helper

I've been looking at a project for a [login module](https://github.com/daddz/sinatra-dm-login/blob/master/models/User.rb), but I'm not sure exactly what this helper method is doing:

```
def self.authenticate(login, pass)
  u = User.first(:login => login)
  return nil if u.nil?
  return u if User.encrypt(pass, u.salt) == u.hashed_password
  nil
end
```

Why not instead of:

```
u = User.first(:login => login)
```

...you do something like:

```
u = self.login
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `first` helper method locates the first record in your database that matches the specified criteria. It's semantically equivalent to the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE login = 'foo' LIMIT 1
```

The code after `u = User.first(:login => login)` does the following:
1. Checks to see if there is a user returned with the specified login
2. Returns the User object if the passwords match.

Answer (score 1):

```
u = User.first(:login => login)
```

means "go to the database, and find me the first User object whose login equals the userid passed in as the "login" parameter.  Assign this to u.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're looking for the corresponding user object, not just the login name.